# excel vba bug with Application.GetSaveAsFilename or Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup)

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing, userform

first time posting but have learned so much in this place already! Now there's an issue for which i do not find a way out..

I have an excel sheet with a bunch of `userforms` which is used for invoicing. In one of the `userforms`, the user has the possibility to print the invoices.
All code runs fine up to the line:

```
fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")
```

Then the computer freezes, and Microsoft Excel is apparently using `>60%` of the processor capacities. After many minutes the "save as" window finally pops open, and all works perfectly again.

I've tried going around this issue and printing to pdf instead of saving to pdf, but the same happens on the line:

```
If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show = True Then
      ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.PrintOut
End If
```

Is there any known issue with this code on weaker computers? All code works fine on my computer, but not on the user's pc.
I've built in stops, and msgboxes on the other parts of the code, just in case the issue would be elsewhere, but it's really only on these lines that the computer panics.

Thanks a lot in advance for any advice!

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems with your code. Such slowdown can occurs when networks are involved, is the default folder distant?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've thought about that too, and then moved the file to the desktop, without any changes. Sometimes it works, but most of the time it bugs until you have to force a shutdown

Comment: Is not there too many files in the default folder? Directory operations over a few hundred files may be shockingly slow even on strong PC's. Another option is to check if Windows can automatically manage virtual memory, because this case looks like having little memory and manually set (limited) virtual memory.